# Bone constraints not working on first bone in chain

Tags: rigging, bones, constraints

I have an IK chain controlling a mesh. I want to attach this IK chain to something. I have tried putting Child Of, Copy Loc, and Copy Transform bone constraints on the start of the chain. None of them do anything. Is there some rule against using constraints on the first bone in a chain? I notice that it works if I constrain the bone in Edit mode with a regular constraint instead of a bone constraint in pose mode, but this causes some strange issues.

Anybody know how I can go about attaching my bone chain? Specifically, I need to have it following a specific vertex (vertex group) on a mesh that is being simmed, so it doesn't work to constrain the entire armature object, or to constrain to the object. Is there an option better than constraining the bone in edit mode to an empty, and then having that empty be constrained to a vertex?

EDIT: Example file (see comments)
[image]

Comment: do you have other constraints on that bone ?

Comment: Yes, I have IK pointing to a vertex group at the bone's tip, but the problem remains even if I disable it. I have found that it works fine to constraint a bone to a vertex group with the constraints listed above if the bone is a single bone, or if the bone is part of a chain. But not if the bone is the head of the chain. For example, I can Child Of a bone to a vertex group at it's head, and IK it to one at it's tail. This causes the bone to move as the mesh it is constrained to moves. But it doesn't work on bones at the start of a chain.

Comment: do you want both head and tail of the chain to keep following the vertex group ? if this is the case parent the IK target to the vertex group as well

Comment: I'm using this specific rig to transfer motion from a simple cloth simmed mesh to a more complex final mesh. So in this case, every bone in the chain is IK'd to a vertex at its tip, and Connected to the bone above it in the chain. But as the cloth object moves (clothing on a character that is moving), the top bone in the chain gets left behind because it's head isn't attached (only its tail through IK.) I need to attach it to the mesh.

However, the problem I am describing appears to happen with any sort of bone chain, not just this strange setup I have.

Comment: can you add the bone chain and the cloth picture ,or a sample file , i can't get the full picture :)

Comment: I cannot share the full file for many reasons, but here's a small file where I've recreated the problem (if dropbox isn't okay, how should I share?)

https://www.dropbox.com/s/x14csvx23dx97ko/BoneChainConstraintProblem.blend?dl=0

Note that the first bone in the chain is Child Of vertex group 0, and IKed to vertex group 1. Enter edit mode and move loops around. If you move loop 0, not happens. If you disable the bone's IK and move loop 0, it rotates but doesn't follow the location. Other bones in the chain are working.

Comment: the main thing is a file with the described problem, I'll try and be back . and for uploading (it's your choice ) but  [see this site with permanent free storage](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com)

Comment: [see this gif](http://www.pasteall.org/pic/85672) is it how you want it to act

Comment: That looks correct from what I can tell from the gif.

Comment: i used the same setup as yours ( child of and IK's) but i can't tell what's wrong with your file

Comment: That is very odd. I made that file totally fresh. Can you share your file so I can compare?

Comment: [Here is the file](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/35172)

Comment: The only difference I can find is that in my version, the first bone has the 'Connected' box checked, but it is greyed out and cannot be unchecked (I know this is normally greyed out in pose mode and can be changed in edit mode. It is greyed out in both.) Your bone has it unchecked. Everything else seems to be the same. Does this mean my bone is somehow parented to something? I originally created my bone chain by selected a vertex loop, duplicating and separating it, and using the Skin modifier to generate an armature. That object has been deleted.

Comment: it should not be checked on the root bone but as you said it have something to do with creation method toggle edit mode and uncheck it and see if it fix it, after that you have to correct the position

Comment: It is greyed out even in edit mode, which is unusual. I will test if this is a problem with Skin or something. That would be problematic as I need to generate a lot of bone chains, and skin is a quick and easy way to do that.

Comment: i did uncheck it in the file you gave me !  let me see again

Comment: even if it is grayed out just click it , it will work

Comment: Aha, yes! That's done it. Thank you! How do we mark this as answered?

Comment: you should write a nice answer and accept it ,so this question get to rest : )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was with the bone at the start of the chain being set as Connected. This is because the bone chain was made using the Skin modifier on a vertex chain. Normally if you add a bone and then extrude it to make a chain, the first bone is not Connected. Apparently the armatures made by Skin are. The Connected checkbox is greyed out, but still can be unchecked. Since the bone has no Parent, the Connected status was locking it in place.